# What configuration need to be changed for DataNode failed to startup and reported `internal TEndPoints can't be modified`?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to change ip address settings in Apache IoTDB. However, after I successfully changed the ip address settings, the system still cannot be restarted. I checked the log records, and find that the problem should be with the startup of DataNode. However, I cannot understand the error message of DataNode, which is `org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.StartupException: Reject DataNode restart. Because the internal TEndPoints of this DataNode can't be modified`. What specific parameter should I change, and what else do I need to do before startup?

Answer (score 0):

Have the configurations of `cn_internal_address` and `dn_internal_address` in Apache IoTDB been changed? These configurations cannot be modified after the first startup of IoTDB. If you need to modify the IP settings, you do not need to modify these two configurations for a stand-alone server. You can just modify `dn_rpc_address`. After resetting the configurations, if there is no actual data yet, just delete the data directory and restart IoTDB, and this problem should be solved.